# Why did Dr. Malcolm suddenly believe Cole?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-sixth-sense

In *The Sixth Sense*, Dr. Malcolm at one point tells Cole that he will not be able to help him and that he will contact someone else that can.

After this, Dr. Malcolm listens to the recordings of himself and Vincent talking. In the recordings Dr. Malcolm can hear "I don't want to die" being repeated over and over in Spanish.

This, somehow, makes Dr. Malcolm change his mind, but I do not understand why.

Prior to listening to the recordings Dr. Malcolm tells Cole that he does not believe that he can see dead people, after listening to it it may seem like Dr. Malcolm changed his mind.

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not all of a sudden. He had listened to these tapes before, but on listening to them again he could hear what could be the ghosts that Vincent was telling him he heard. That would support the claim that Cole can actually see dead people.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sixth_Sense):

> At first, Crowe thinks Cole is delusional and considers dropping his case. Remembering Vincent, the psychologist listens to an audiotape from a session with Vincent when he was a child. On the tape, when Crowe leaves the room, Vincent begins crying. Turning up the volume, Crowe hears a weeping man begging for help in Spanish, and now believes that Cole is telling the truth and that Vincent may have had the same ability.

Because he feels guilty for not being able to help Vincent, and not wanting to make the same mistake again Dr. Malcom decides to trust that Cole is telling the truth.

Comment: So, the voice we hear speaking Spanish is NOT Vincents? Or is it his?

Comment: @OptimusCrime Crowe leaves Vincent alone, but we can hear another voice, a ghost's voice (Vincent probably doesn't speak Spanish). If that seems impossible (why didn't that happen before), remember that ghosts only see and hear what they want to; in that case, Crowe wants to believe the child (he feels guilty about Vincent). When he "hears" the recorded ghost's voice, I believe he is just unconsciously finding a reason to help Cole. Note that it doesn't contradict whether Vincent could actually interact with ghosts or not.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Luciano's answer on the tape you hear that when Dr. Malcolm reenters, he says that it is surprisingly cold. Cole mentioned that the presence of dead people makes the temperature drop before.